# Scrape "alt" from img with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, image, web-scraping, alt

I am trying to scrape a walkscore from www.walkscore.com because their API doesn't support my country. The problem i am facing; the walkscore they present is stored in an img with the value i want to scrape in the "alt" section. As im quite new to scraping through excel VBA i am stuck.

Only one score, which is in the "alt" is needed for one search and store it in a specific cell. For now i just have used A10 as an example, but i will fix that later.

See the code i have now:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Blad1


Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.walkscore.com/score/18-lindegracht-alkmaar-nh-netherlands"
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = IE.document

Set ClassCol = Doc.getElementsByClassName("blok-header-badge.score-info-link")
Set ElementCol = ClassCol.getElementsByTagName("img")

For Each Link In ElementCol

    ws.Range("A10").Value = Link.getAttritube("alt")

Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `XMLHttpRequest` request to get the required content instead of piloting IE which is cumbersome. This is how you can go:

Using XMLHttpRequest:

```
Sub FetchAlt()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.walkscore.com/score/18-lindegracht-alkmaar-nh-netherlands"
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, sAlt$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        sAlt = HTML.querySelector(".score-info-link > img").getAttribute("alt")
        MsgBox sAlt
    End With
End Sub
```

Using IE:

```
Sub FetchAlt()
    Dim oWalk As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "https://www.walkscore.com/score/18-lindegracht-alkmaar-nh-netherlands"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set oWalk = .document.querySelector(".score-info-link > img")
        Debug.Print oWalk.getAttribute("alt")
    End With
End Sub
```

They both produce the following output:

```
97 Walk Score of 18 Lindegracht Alkmaar NH Netherlands
```

Comment: Wow perfect! This is even faster and worked perfecty. Thanks :)